# how to get image url in ember using active admin gem

Tags: ember.js, activeadmin, ember-rails

rails gem. I have add active admin gem to the app.

When i add image to a product model in active admin it gets uploaded but when i make a call to model the image attr looks like [Object Object] in ember inspector.

How can i display image or get image url

my product serialzer

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description , :image
end
```

my ember product model

```
MyApp.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  image: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category'),
});
```

Comment: What uploading library are you using for Rails? It might be better to serialize `:image_url`, or similar method, for Ember.

Comment: I am using carrierwave